# Playing background music android error

Tags: java, android, audio

Here is the code I know causes the error:

```
final MediaPlayer background = MediaPlayer.create(Start.this, R.raw.music);
    background.setLooping(true); // Set looping
    background.setVolume(100,100);
    background.start();

    final ImageButton mute = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.mute);
    final boolean[] mute_off = {true};

    mute.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            background.stop();

            if (mute_off[0]) {
                mute.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sound_off);
                mute_off[0] = true;
            } else {
                mute.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sound_on);
                mute_off[0] = false;
            }
        }
    });
```

When I launch the app, it crashes and the error is: *"unfortunately, app has stopped working"*

caused by (from logcat):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

What is happening?

Comment: The setVolume method takes a float volume in range 0.0 to 1.0. Why do you have 100, 100. Regarding the exception, post your logcat stack trace error report.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine excluding you are giving wrong ids or image is not present in drawable. This much is working fine

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final MediaPlayer background = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sun);
        background.setLooping(true); // Set looping
        background.setVolume(100,100);
        background.start();

        final ImageButton mute = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.edt1);
        final boolean[] mute_off = {true};

        mute.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                background.stop();

                if (mute_off[0]) {
                    Log.v("value is======", "true");
                   // mute.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sound_off);
                    mute_off[0] = true;
                } else {
                    Log.v("value is======", "false");
                  //  mute.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sound_on);
                    mute_off[0] = false;
                }
            }
        });
```